# ¿Como abrir un un activity desde un listview con su propia información?

Tags: android, listview, activity, click

quisiera que me ayudaran, tengo que abrir un activity con la información detallada del item que fue clicado, desde un lisview.

solo que quisiera que no fuera por position, ya que cuando implemento un buscador para el listview, me cambia la posición.   Abajo le dejo mi codigo fuente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewContry);

    ArrayList<String> arraycontryList = new ArrayList<>();
    arraycontryList.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_Contry)));


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraycontryList);
    lv .setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

---

**activity_detalle.xml**

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Titulo"
    android:layout_width="386dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
    tools:text="Marta" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/foto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Titulo"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/images" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="351dp"
    android:layout_height="146dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/foto"
    tools:text="sdasda as dasd asdasd adas dasd asdasdasdasd/>
```

---

**DetalleActivity.java**

```
public class DetalleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);
}
```

}

---

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Listarybuscar</string>


<string-array name="array_Contry">

    <item>  hugo    </item>
    <item>  pedro   </item>
    <item>  maria   </item>
    <item>  juan    </item>
    <item>  marta   </item>
    <item>  lucas   </item>
    <item>  monica  </item>
    <item>  luna    </item>
    <item>  perico  </item>
    <item>  masda   </item>
    <item>  asdfasdf</item>
    <item>  oscar   </item>
    <item>  mondoza</item>
    <item>  mocas   </item>
    <item>  mosaxca</item>
    <item>  posacangre</item>


</string-array>


<string-array name="array_Descripcion">

    <item>
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    </item>

    <item>
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    </item>

    <item>
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    </item>
    <item>
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    </item>

</string-array>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Map

Una forma de lograr lo que usted quiere, es utilizando un Map. Map es una tipo de arreglo que permite almacenar datos en pares clave valor, los valores que se almacenan en cada posición de este tipo de arreglo van acompañados de una clave, la cual entre otras cosa se utiliza para acceder a los valores almacenados en las diferentes posiciones del arreglo. Puede encontrar un buen tutorial de como utilizar este arreglo en [Jarroba](https://jarroba.com/map-en-java-con-ejemplos/).

#### Esto es un Map:

```
Map<String, String> frutas = HasMap<String, String>();
frutas.put("mango", "El mango es una fruta tropical de sabor dulce.");
frutas.put("sandia", "La sandia es una fruta con un alto contenido de agua.");
frutas.put("manzana", "La manzana es una fruta de color rojo y es muy consumida en navidad.");

String mango = frutas.get("mango");
System.out.println(mango)
```

## Solución

Para lograr lo que usted quiere, tiene que crear un Map en el que almacene las descripciones como valores y a cada descripción le asigne como clave su titulo correspondiente. Luego para obtener una descripción almacenada en el Map solo tiene que utilizar la clave que utilizo para almacenarlo. El Map debe de crearlo como variable de la clase y rellenarlo en el onCreate() con los datos de los Array títulos y descripciones, los títulos los utilizara como clave y las descripciones como valor.

Luego en el OnItemClickListener() debe de obtener el titulo almacenado en la posición seleccionada por el usuario y pasarlo como parámetro al método `get()` del Map. De esa manera obtendrá la descripción que almacena el Map con ese titulo como clave. De esa forma podrá acceder a la descripción correcta sin importar la posición, ya que las descripciones estarán relacionadas con los títulos.

#### Creación del Map

```
// La variable de tipo Map se tiene que declarar como variable de la clase
// para poder usarla en el OnItemClickListener().
Map<String, String> descripciones = new HasMap<String, String>();

// En el onCreate() rellenamos el Map.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Se obtienen los arrays de los recursos.
    String[] ArrayTitulos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_Contry);
    String[] ArrayDescripciones = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_Descripcion);

    // Se recorren los arrays y se almacenan sus valores en el Map.
    for (int i = 0; i < ArrayDescripciones.length; i++){

        descripciones.put(ArrayTitulos[i], ArrayDescripciones[i]);
    }

}
```

#### Obtencion de las descripciones

```
List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Se obtiene el titulo de la posicion seleccionada por el usuario. 
        TextView textView = (TextView)view;
        String textTitulo = textView.getText();

        // Se obtiene la descripcion almacenada en el Map con el titulo como clave.
        String textDescripcion = descripciones.get(textTitulo);  

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("clave_titulo", textTitulo);
        intent.putExtra("clave_descripcion", textDescripcion);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias lo Intentaré me gusta =)

Comment: ** que se pueda hacer pero NO POR POSICION, **                              
             String textDescripcion = descripciones[position];

Comment: habrá una forma que sea por contenido explicito.

Comment: Puedes compartir el codigo que utilizas para realizar la busqueda.

Comment: CODIGO -->  
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EfADIUxlXMhlWnUgsugIq7YkFBdiSovJS9eI_GiK464/edit

Comment: @Carlos si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: HOLA DAVID, LO REVISARE Y ESTUDIARÉ PARA APLICARLO, GRACIAS. BENDICIONES

Comment: @Carlos si la respuesta te es de ayuda, la mejor forma de dar las gracias es realizando alguna acción, como darle un voto positivo a la respuesta, marcarla como aceptada o ambas.

Comment: Hola David, muy buena respuesta ya la marque, tambien se podrian agregar las fotos, =) ¿Donde estudiaste TOdo esto?

Comment: Pues soy autodidacta y he investigado el tema de los arrays. Sabiendo como funcionan los array, me di cuenta que en este caso el array Map solucionaba el problema. En Internet aparece toda la información que se necesite para realizar cualquier cosa, solo hay que investigar y poner en practica lo aprendido.

Comment: Para tratar el tema de las fotos accede a esta sala de chat [ListaryBuscar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64208/listarybuscar).

Comment: Hola @Carlos   como vas en tu desarrollo?

Comment: Bien funciono muy bien, Tal vez me puedas ayudar. quisiera hacer un listview normal y que tenga la opcion cuando mantenga presionado de agregarlo en un apartado de favoritos, pero solo sé hacer el listview normal, Será tan amble de ayudarme. Bendiciones.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96442/como-hacer-un-apartado-para-favoritos

Answer (score 0):

**Tienes que hacer lo siguiente:**

*Hacer referencia a la lista, esto lo puedes hacer en el **onCreate** del **MainActivity***

> ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewContry);

*Posteriormente agregar el evento **setOnItemClickListener** para detectar cuando se le de clic a algun elemento de la lista.*
Al igual puedes hacer uso de **Intent** y **putExtra** para abrir la actividad y enviar datos después de dar clic.

```
            List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info","miinfo");
                    intent.putExtra("info2","miinfo2");
                    intent.putExtra("info3","miinfo3");
                    intent.putExtra("info4","miinfo4");
                    intent.putExtra("info5","miinfo5");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Posteriormente en tu **DetalleActivity**, capturas los datos que enviaste desde la lista que tienes en tu **MainActivity**.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);

    *//referencias que a tus views de activity_detalle.xml*
    titulo    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Titulo);
    imgPerfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
    address   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Capturas la informacion enviada
    tituloExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("info");
    urlImage    = getIntent().getStringExtra("info2");
    descripcion = getIntent().getStringExtra("info4");

    //asignas la información a tus TexView,ImageView, etc...
    titulo.setText(tituloExtra );
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: Donde dice. putExtra("info",**"miinfo"** );.... como hago para ponerle la información de marta, la foto...? Perdoneme esque soy nuevo en esto. y me cuesta mucho. Gracias

Comment: por que la descripcion la tengo en un <string-array name="array_descipcion">                      y la img espesifica no se como agregarla =) perdoneme mi inorancia esque estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Obtener la información dependiente de la posición es a lo que te refieres? Ejemplo si selecciono el elemento 3 debes o deberías de buscar en strings.xml en nombre de tu array la posición igual número 3? Es a lo que te refieres o estoy equivocado?